# How to design all-pass filter by specifying phase requirements?

Tags: phase, infinite-impulse-response, group-delay

I want to delay the part of signal above (or below) specified frequency, but I don't find any books or tutorials to tell how to design is. The commonly used biquad APFs (such as the one introduced in [this cookbook](http://shepazu.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html)) produce a zigzag-shaped phase response, that is not I want.

How can I do it? Thanks for a lot!

Comment: "zigzag-shaped phase response, that is not I want"  Are you sure?  Are you aware that the group delay curve is the derivative of the phase curve?  So even a constant delay at all frequencies produces a zig-zag phase curve when the phase wraps around?